# React Carousel / Image Slider

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm making a image slider in react JSX for profile section,bt it's not working.

```
import React from 'react';
import AwesomeSlider from 'react-awesome-slider';
import 'react-awesome-slider/dist/styles.css';

const slider = (
  <AwesomeSlider>
    <div data-src={require('../assets/icons/s1.jpg')} />
    <div data-src={require('../assets/icons/s2.jpg')} />
    <div data-src={require('../assets/icons/s3.jpg')} />
  </AwesomeSlider>
);
export default slider;
```

Error:Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `App`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `slider` as an component it has to return a function:

```
const Slider = ({props}) => (
    <AwesomeSlider>
        <div data-src={require('./assets/icons/s1.jpg')}/>
        <div data-src={require('./assets/icons/s2.jpg')}/>
        <div data-src={require('./assets/icons/s3.jpg')}/>
    </AwesomeSlider>
);
export default Slider;
```